# Which event fires every time in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, events, global-asax

I know that `Global.asax` has events which fire for an application at a specific time. But I need an `event` which fires every time the application receives a request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `Global.asax` event `Application_BeginRequest` fire every time when a page request made.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is the `Application_BeginRequest` event:

> Fired when an application request is received. It's the first event fired for a request, which is often a page request (URL) that a user enters.

For more event information, have a look on this article
[Working with the ASP.NET Global.asax file](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/5771721)